# How do I copy the files from one branch to another branch?

Tags: svn

I have something like this:

```
/repo/branch-a/foo/apples
/repo/branch-a/foo/oranges
/repo/branch-a/bar/broccoli
/repo/branch-a/bar/potato
/repo/branch-b/snazz
/repo/branch-b/jazz
```

now I want to move the snazz folder into a third subfolder of branch-b 'barfoo'

eg, afterwards, it will look like:

```
/repo/branch-a/foo/apples
/repo/branch-a/foo/oranges
/repo/branch-a/bar/broccoli
/repo/branch-a/bar/potato
/repo/branch-a/barfoo/snazz
/repo/branch-b/barfoo/jazz
/repo/branch-b/snazz
/repo/branch-b/jazz
```

The way I had initially tried to do this, was check out branch-a, and check out branch -b. Create the barfoo folder in branch-a, and then copy the snazz and jazz folders into barfoo folder.

The problem with this, is that the copy copies all the .svn folders, and so when you try commit, the files in those folders are still pointing back at the branch-b repo.

I could go through and delete all the .svn folders, but if there are a lot of subfolders, then this is quite time consuming, and not a good solution.

Comment: If you update to a newer SVN version (1.6+ ?) you will find that it creates only one .svn folder in root. That's much more convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work with a Windows/Tortoise SVN:

I would checkout the repo, then move `snazz` and `jazz` with right mouse button from `branch-a` to `branch-b` and select "SVN move versioned items here". This way you will have SVN history preserved.

Comment: +1 This is absolutely the proper way. (Dunno about doing it with the mouse, but this is `svn cp repo:/src repo:/dest; svn rm repo:/src`)

Comment: @triplee: You can append this to my answer or post a new one. I would +1 this )

Answer (score 0):

instead of copying, export them. if you export, its going to copy only the files not the .svn files.
tortoisesvn has this option, you can drag and drop with the right click and choose export all.

Comment: -1 Exporting and reimporting loses the historical record and ignores the mechanism the SVN provides for precisely this sort of scenario.